# How do I trigger the scroll of an inner component whilst scrolling through the regular document in CSS? (I'm using React.js with Styled Components)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scroll, styled-components

[This is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mra48.png)

In the image, you can see a yellow section that is within a green section. When the user is scrolling and they enter the green section, I want the page to stop and finish scrolling through the yellow section before continuing to scroll the entire page. In other words, the user should not be able to skip scrolling through the yellow section; it should be treated as a part of the page rather than some div with an (overflow: scroll;) property implemented upon it.

I'm using React.js with Styled Components and Next.js
For reference, here is the code I have so far:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Image from 'next/image';

const Section2 = () => {


  return (
  <>
  <Section>
    <Content>
      <Slide1></Slide1>
      <Slide1 style={{backgroundColor:"orange"}}></Slide1>
      <Slide1></Slide1>

    </Content>

  </Section>

  </>
  )
}

const Section = styled.section`
display: flex;
height: 80vh;
background-color: lightgreen;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
overflow: hidden;
`
const Content = styled.div`
display: flex;
height: 20vw;
width: 40vw;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: 10vw;
background-color: red;
overflow-y: auto;
scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; 
scroll-behavior: smooth;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
flex-direction: column;
`
const Slide1 = styled.div`
scroll-snap-align: start;
flex-shrink: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #eee;
transform-origin: center center;
transform: scale(1);
transition: transform 0.5s;
position: relative;

display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 100px;
background-color: yellow;
`


export default Section2
```

With an issue like this, I don't know where to begin. I think that when the user scrolls down to the green section and starts scrolling the regular page, this should trigger the scroll bar for the yellow section somehow, but I have no idea how to implement this in the code.

I think some could describe this as a parallax scrolling effect, but I'm not sure. This is a similar implementation to what I'm describing: [Click here](https://codemyui.com/split-screen-text-and-image-with-load-more-on-scroll/).

If someone could be an angel and offer support, I would gladly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.